# So online video files can have previews as well?

Tags: html, video

So I found a video in a site that had a paywall, but did have a preview before it paused. I won't show the for personal reasons.

However, I opened the video address in a new tab. And things got worse and more interesting. The video was your typical online .mp4 video you can open up on Google. But it was also a preview.

It had the full video, but only allowed you to watch a small portion of it. And when it stopped and I pressed play, the playback when back to the beginning. And to make matters weirder, when I downloaded the video it only downloaded a small part of it.

So is there a way to edit a video or link that has that, or is it more complex, because I'm not programming genius or anything like that.

I did try going on inspect and tackling it through finding the mp4 on the Elements and network, just to find the same link.

Here's part of the link that I feel is important: ?temp_url_expires=1669424929&temp_url_id=086f4628-ce77-48b9-89f7-e24f3b3f3848&countable=true&filename=resolution_360p&inline=true&content_type=video/mp4&concurrency=32&rate_limit=0&response_limit=5595000&ip_access_policy=everyone&tags=file_type:video_360p,action:limited_view,project:partner,user_file_id:78fadc91d74d7,user_id:&temp_url_issuer=5445f78a91de707b297e67ed&temp_url_sig=7642ffa346f89a78fbef781d5c5e5e6ed7625a323c680192032f3c95611046f4b236e0c0bdc83a757e343837d2e6573cb5d47dd2c272242a320eb1ff3e401335&client_ip=

Comment: The same way a server can only output half a page of text to you, it can also only send the bytes for half a video. If the video is encoded properly, that's not even going to break it. It's either this, or the full video uses a different URL to a full version.

Comment: I guess those could be the case